# How to sort based on keyword first?

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, select, sql-order-by

Here is a sample Database

```
First_name      country
Andy            US
Manu            India
Paul            Pakistan
Ramesh          Pakistan
Rich            India
```

So, what i want is to select all records from the above table and display according to name. 
Like :-

I want to select person name to be display first whose country name is India and after US, Pakistan.
How can i perform this task in single SQL query ?

**Update**

I don't know how many Country are there.

Country the need to be display first will be input by the user.

Comment: If you dont know howmany country then how can you give in order clause?

Comment: better way to write stored procedure with dynamic sql queries

Comment: @Sadikhasan ok let say i have 50 fixed country in my sql then ?

Comment: Then you have to mention country order clause as given answer by @SaharashShah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a CASE statement to give each record a sortkey. 0 for a country match, 1 for a mismatch, so the desired country comes first.

```
select *
from mytable
order by case when country = @country then 0 else 1 end, first_name
```

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this

```
Select * From Table1
Order By CASE WHEN country = 'INDIA' THEN 0
              WHEN country = 'US' THEN 1
              Esle 2
         END;
```

Or You can use **[FIELD](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-field-function.php)**

```
Select * From Table1 Order By FIELD(country, 'India', 'US', 'Pakistan') ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [**FIELD**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_field) Function

Try this:

```
SELECT fitst_name, country 
FROM tableA 
ORDER BY FIELD(country, 'India', 'US', 'Pakistan'), fitst_name
```